# Spring 4 + Hibernate 5 + JPA + c3p0: dataSource not being recognized

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I'm attempting to upgrade an existing application (not mine) to use Hibernate 5, JPA, c3P0, and Spring 4. The issue that I'm having is in the SchemaCreator class, it's not picking up the hibernate connection details from the dataSource bean (uses c3p0).

However, in the existing code it's explicitly passing the dialect through annotations, which I'm wondering if that's needed. I admit I'm a bit rusty and reading the tutorials doesn't look like the existing code I'm trying to maintain (oss). This is my first step towards slowly upgrading to Spring 5 ultimately.

Here is what I'm dealing with....

pom.xml versions:

```
  <spring.version>4.3.30.RELEASE</spring.version>
  <c3p0.version>0.9.5.5</c3p0.version>
  <hibernate.version>5.6.4.Final</hibernate.version>
  <hibernate-jpa-api.version>1.0.0.Final</hibernate-jpa-api.version>
  <hsqldb.version>2.7.0</hsqldb.version>

  ....
            <dependency>
              <groupId>com.mchange</groupId>
              <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
              <version>${c3p0.version}</version>
           </dependency>
           <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
                <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
                <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
                <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
                <version>${hibernate-jpa-api.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
                <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-tools</artifactId>
                <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
                <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
            </dependency>
  ...
```

baseContext.xml looks like...

```
<bean id="propertyConfigurer" class="org.springframework.context.support.PortalPropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <value>classpath:datasource.properties</value>
                <value>classpath:configuration.properties</value>
                <value>file:${portal.home}/global.properties</value>
                <value>file:${portal.home}/simple-cms.properties</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
    
   <bean id="propertyResolver" factory-bean="propertyConfigurer" factory-method="getPropertyResolver"/>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" destroy-method="close"
          p:driverClass="${hibernate.connection.driver_class}"
          p:jdbcUrl="${hibernate.connection.url}"
          p:user="${hibernate.connection.username}"
          p:password="${hibernate.connection.password}">

        <property name="acquireIncrement" value="1"/>
        <property name="minPoolSize" value="1"/>
        <property name="initialPoolSize" value="1"/>
        <property name="maxPoolSize" value="5"/>
        <property name="maxIdleTime" value="900"/>
        <property name="testConnectionOnCheckout" value="true"/>
        <property name="contextClassLoaderSource" value="library"/>
        <property name="privilegeSpawnedThreads" value="true"/>
        <!-- End of c3p0 properties -->
    </bean>

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
          <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
        </property>
        <property name="jpaProperties">
          <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
          </props>
        </property>
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="AttachmentsDb" />
    </bean>


    <bean class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor"/>

    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" proxy-target-class="true"/>

    <bean id="schemaCreator" class="org.jasig.portlet.attachment.util.SchemaCreator" />
...
```

Then I have the SchemaCreator class where I had to do some adjustments once switching to Hibernate 5. The original code has an annotation of the hibernate dialect, and if I add the connection details in the same way, I don't receive errors.

However, shouldn't the dataSource bean be available since I've included it in the **entityManagerFactory** bean?

It seems to be getting left out. Most of the examples I see use sessionFactory, but this one isn't, it's also using the **Connection** class, which I'm wondering if that's still needed when using JPA.

The errors that I'm getting now is that it can't find an available JDBC driver.

Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver

```
public class SchemaCreator implements ApplicationContextAware {

    private static final String APPLICATION_CONTEXT_LOCATION = "classpath:/context/baseContext.xml";

    private static final String DATA_SOURCE_BEAN_NAME = "dataSource";

    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

    <!-- Should I pass the other hibernate connection details like this?-->
    @Value("${hibernate.dialect}")
    private String hibernateDialect;
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Bootstrap an ApplicationContext...
        final GenericApplicationContext context = new GenericApplicationContext();
        final XmlBeanDefinitionReader reader = new XmlBeanDefinitionReader(context);

        final Resource resource = context.getResource(APPLICATION_CONTEXT_LOCATION);
        reader.loadBeanDefinitions(resource);

        context.refresh();
        context.registerShutdownHook(); // close this context on JVM shutdown unless it has already been closed.

        final SchemaCreator schemaCreator = context.getBean("schemaCreator", SchemaCreator.class);
        System.exit(schemaCreator.create());
    }

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }

    private int create() {
           
        final DataSource dataSource = applicationContext.getBean(DATA_SOURCE_BEAN_NAME, DataSource.class);

        try (final Connection conn = dataSource.getConnection()) { 
            Map<String, String> settings = new HashMap<>();
            settings.put("generateDdl", "false");
            settings.put("hibernate.dialect",hibernateDialect);

            ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(settings).build();
            MetadataSources metadata = new MetadataSources(serviceRegistry);
            metadata.addAnnotatedClass(Attachment.class);

            EnumSet<TargetType> enumSet = EnumSet.of(TargetType.DATABASE);
            SchemaExport schemaExport = new SchemaExport();
            schemaExport.execute(enumSet, SchemaExport.Action.BOTH, metadata.buildMetadata());  

            final List<Exception> exceptions = schemaExport.getExceptions();
            if (exceptions.size() != 0) {
                logger.error("Schema Create Failed;  see below for details");
                for (Exception e : exceptions) {
                    logger.error("Exception from Hibernate Tools SchemaExport", e);
                }
                return 1;
            }
        } catch (SQLException sqle) {
            logger.error("Failed to initialize & invoke the SchemaExport tool", sqle);
            return 1;
        }

        return 0;
    }

}
```

Thanks for any assistance. I feel like I'm putting together Frankenstein right now and it's frustrating :)

-L

Comment: Hibernate easily gets confused if the JDBC URL is not valid. Check to make sure it actually works.

Comment: Yes, I confirmed it worked by passing the connection details using annotations like what had been done with the hibernate.dialect, like so, @Value("${hibernate.connection.url}"). But, when I pass the dataSource bean into the entityManagerFactory bean, shouldn't that have been taken care of? I feel like that's not the right way if I pass them all using annotations. I could be wrong though

Comment: The `SchemaCreator` is quite a frankenstein. You aren't using the `EntityManagerFactory` in your `SchemaCreator` but are recreating the inernals of it (the `ServiceRegistry`) which doesn't know anything about the internals. Re-use the existing `EntityManagerFactory` instead of recreating it.

Answer (score 0):

So I am not sure why this wasn't necessary before, but I had a database.properties file and a hibernate.properties file.

The database.properties had the connection details, but the hibernate.properties file did not. I added the connection details to hibernate.properties and I don't get the errors anymore.

I'm not certain if there was a change in Hibernate 5 that by default it checks for a hibernate.properties file. Yet, in my baseContext.xml  I set the location of the database properties file.

```
<value>classpath:datasource.properties</value>
```

Does this make sense? Is this something about hibernate 5?

If anyone can validate my assumption, I'd love to hear it because I feel empty thinking that was the fix.